# I want to create a trigger in mysql which insert a row in a table when update a row in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger in mysql which insert a row in a table change_history when there is any update in another table event_data if event_data.title='event_media'.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_evdata_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON event_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if OLD.title <=> 'event_media'
    INSERT INTO change_history (badge,city,country,venue,company,
date,rehosted,type,cancelled,name,tagline,description,agenda,pricing,
edition,photo_video,exhibitors,speakers,official_url,twitter_handle,
twitter_hashtag,facebook_url,contact,post_review_id) values(1,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null);
end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO change_history (badge,city,country,venue,company,
date,rehosted,typ'

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. Please try.

```
BEGIN
IF (OLD.title <> 'event_media')
    THEN
INSERT INTO `change_history` (`xxx_id`,`and_all_other_fields_similar_way`)
 VALUES (old.xxx_id,old.and_all_other_fields_similar_way); 
END IF;
END
```

Comment: where would i declare the variable in trigger

Comment: which variable?

Can you share the create code for both the tables with some sample data please?

Comment: @FaisalRehman . . . I think the point is that you need the `THEN` keyword.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `after_evdata_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON event_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if( OLD.title <=> 'event_media')
THEN
    INSERT INTO change_history (badge,0,null)
end if;
END;

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `ABCD` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `ABCD` AFTER UPDATE ON  `event_data` FOR EACH ROW IF( OLD.value != NEW.value ) THEN INSERT INTO change_history( badge ) 
SELECT  '1'
FROM event_data
WHERE OLD.title =  'event_media'
AND id = NEW.id;

END IF..........it is working now..bye the thanks